# An example of a non-diagonalisable matrix in $\mathrm{SL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$ whose eigenvalues don't all have absolute value $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was wondering if there exists a matrix $M \in \mathrm{SL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$, such that:

- $M$ is not diagonalisable;
- $M$ does **not** have all eigenvalues with absolute value $1$.

**Thoughts**: The only non-diagonalisable matrix in $\mathrm{SL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$ I can think of are the ones consisting of Jordan block with $\pm 1$ on the diagonal.

Any hint on how to construct such a matrix would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 7 & 2\end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: This matrix is not in $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @BranimirĆaćić Thanks for pointing that. I edited.

Answer (score 5):

The matrix $A$ has no eigenvalues of modulus $1$ and is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$:
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 3 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 3\\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for such matrices!