# An example of a non-diagonalisable matrix in $\mathrm{SL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$ whose Jordan blocks don't have determinant $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does there exists a matrix $M \in \mathrm{SL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$, such that:

- $M$ is not diagonalisable;
- when we put $M$ in its Jordan normal form, **none** of the Jordan blocks have a determinant with an absolute value of $1$?

**Where I got this question from**: This is a follow-up question to the one I ask [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4465992/976076). Thank you to those who provided the examples. So far, the examples are all made up of submatrices with determinant $1$. I was wondering if there are matrices that are not of this form. So maybe a matrix with its Jordan normal form looks like this, with $|\lambda_1|^2 \ne 1$ and $|\lambda_2|^3 \ne 1$.

$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda_1  & 1  & 0 & 0& 0\\
 0 &  \lambda_1 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \lambda_2 & 1& 0 \\
 0 &  0 & 0 & \lambda_2& 1 \\
 0 &  0 & 0 & 0& \lambda_2 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example :

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&1&1\\ 1 & -6&1&1 \\ 0& 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0& 0 & 1 & -6 \end{pmatrix}$$

Indeed, the Jordan normal form of $A$ is $$ J=\begin{pmatrix} -3-\sqrt{10}&1&0&0\\ 0 & -3-\sqrt{10}&0&0 \\ 0& 0 & -3+\sqrt{10} & 1 \\ 0& 0 & 0 & -3+\sqrt{10} \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: on his more recent question I put a 9 by 9 example; you had deleted your answer there.  For prime $p,$   matrix size $p$ by $p$  seems unworkable.   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4466904/an-example-of-a-non-diagonalisable-matrix-in-mathrmsl5-mathbbz-whose/4466978#4466978

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, nice $9 \times 9$ example. My answer made no sense at all, but indeed, I think you are right to say that $5 \times 5$ does not work.