# An example of a non-diagonalisable matrix in $\mathrm{SL}(5, \mathbb{Z})$ whose Jordan blocks don't have determinant $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does there exists a matrix $M \in \mathrm{SL}(5, \mathbb{Z})$, such that:

- $M$ is not diagonalisable;
- Let $J$ be the Jordan normal form of $M$, $J$ has one Jordan block of size $3$ and one Jordan block of size $2$, and **none** of the Jordan blocks have a determinant with an absolute value of $1$? So $J$ looks like this,
  $$
  J =
  \left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  \lambda_1  & 1  & 0 & 0& 0\\
   0 &  \lambda_1 & 0 & 0& 0 \\
   0 & 0 & \lambda_2 & 1& 0 \\
   0 &  0 & 0 & \lambda_2& 1 \\
   0 &  0 & 0 & 0& \lambda_2 \\
  \end{array}
  \right).
  $$
  with $|\lambda_1|^2 \ne 1$ and $|\lambda_2|^3 \ne 1$?

**Where I got this question from**: This is a follow-up question to the one I ask [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4466761/976076). (Thank you, TheSilverDoe, who answered my previous questions). So far, all the examples are made up of "smaller" $2$ by $2$ submatrices. I was wondering if there are matrices that are not of this form, e.g. a matrix with an odd degree.

Thanks for your time reading and help in advance.

Comment: Jordan form over what field? Certainly not over $\mathbb{Q}$...

Answer (score 6):

5 does not seem workable. However, 9 by 9

$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc}         
 0&1&0&    1&0&0&    0&0&0\\
      0&0&1&     0&1&0&    0&0&0\\
      1&3&0&     0&0&1&    0&0&0\\ \hline
      0&0&0&     0&1&0&    1&0&0\\
      0&0&0&     0&0&1&    0&1&0\\
      0&0&0&     1&3&0&    0&0&1\\ \hline
     0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&1&0\\
      0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&0&1\\  
    0&0&0&     0&0&0&    1&3&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Nice answer by Arturo about:  a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if the **minimal** polynomial is squarefree  ( and the roots are in the field being used) [Minimal polynomial and diagonalizable matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56745/minimal-polynomial-and-diagonalizable-matrix)

For the 9 by 9 matrix above, the characteristic and minimal polynomials coincide,  each is $(x^3 -3x-1)^3 ,$  thus repeated roots.

$$
A^3 - 3A - I =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr|rrr|rrr}         
 0&0&0&    -3&0&3&         0&3&0\\
      0&0&0&     3&6&0&    0&0&3\\
      0&0&0&     0&3&6&    3&9&0\\ \hline
      0&0&0&     0&0&0&    -3&0&3\\
      0&0&0&     0&0&0&    3&6&0\\
      0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&3&6\\ \hline
     0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&0&0\\
      0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&0&0\\  
    0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
(A^3 - 3A - I)^2 =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc}         
 0&0&0&    0&0&0&         9&9&9\\
      0&0&0&     0&0&0&    9&36&9\\
      0&0&0&     0&0&0&    9&36&36\\ \hline
      0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&0&0\\
      0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&0&0\\
      0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&0&0\\ \hline
     0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&0&0\\
      0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&0&0\\  
    0&0&0&     0&0&0&    0&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: But what about its Jordan blocks?

Comment: @Ruy three real irrational eigenvalues, one full size (3 by 3) block for each

Comment: Ok, I see you read it off from the minimal polynomial.  However I'm not yet convinced all three roots have geometric multiplicity 1.  How do you know the minimal polynomial isn't e.g $$(x-a_1)^3(x-a_2)(x-a_3),$$ where the $a_i$ are the eigenvalues?

Comment: @Ruy  the characteristic and minimal polynomials coincide here. The minimal polynomial has integer coefficients and divides the characteristic.  The candidates are $x^3 - 3x-1, (x^3 - 3x - 1)^2, (x^3-3x-1)^3$

Comment: Ok, so it all follows from the fact that $x^3-3x-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Ruy   yes, the roots are $ -2 \cos \frac{2\pi}{9}  ,  \;  -2 \cos \frac{4\pi}{9}  ,  \;  -2 \cos \frac{8\pi}{9}  . \;   \; \; $